# grayscale image creation 16 bits

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, graphics, opencv3.0

I am using openCV for the first time. I am using openCV3 and XCode to code it. I want to create a 16 bit grayscale image but I want to the data I have is defined such that 4000 is the pixel value for white and 0 for black. I have the information for these pixels in an array of type  int. How can I create a Mat and assign the values in the array to the Mat?

Answer (score 3):

```
short data[] = { 0,0,4000,4000,0,0,4000, ...};
Mat gray16 = Mat(h, w, CV_16S, data);
```

again, the types must match. for 16bit, you need CV_16S and a `short`array, for 8bit CV_8U and a uchar* array, for float CV_32S and a float* ....

Comment: can I do it using a long int array and CV_16UC1?

Comment: no. you either have to make a CV_32S Mat (assuming, long int has 32bits on your machine), or write a loop, where you copy each single element.

Comment: @berak Great Thanks for explaining types

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Mat with

```
cv::Mat m(rows, cols, CV_16UC1);
```

but to my knowledge, there is no way to define a custom value for "white", you'll have to multiply *m* with *std::numeric_limits::max / 4000*. However, this is only necessary when displaying the image.

A lookup-table could do the same (potentially slower), see cv::LUT. However, it appearently only supports 8-bit images.

edit: OK, I missed the part about assigning existing array values; see berak's answer. I hope the answer is still useful.

Comment: If i create it using the way defined by berak, how can I scale the values such that white is 65535 and black is 0? How does the multiplies works? I am new to all this so I have too many questions.

Comment: For display purposes, definition of *white* or *"fully opaque"* will always be the largest value in scale, so 65535 will implicitly be white. This is why you have to scale up with a factor so that 4000 won't appear dark.
In OpenCV, you can just use the multiply operator to scale your image: *m *= 65353/4000*